# Windows Phone 8 resume/suspend /activated/deactivated

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am currently trying to make an app that takes some data from a server. I have a list and I am populating it when I login with some data. The idea is that that data can change over short periods of time. I made an auto refresh button, works fine, but I wanted to implement something like this:

- When you open the app, everything loads, is good (done).
- If you minimize (put in taskbar, I don't know how to say, enter on another app or menu). Your app will be suspended. When you resume it, I want it to perform the refresh thing. (Need help).

I'm currently working with Windows Phone 8, started project on this one and want to finish with this one. `App.current.` doesn't have `resume` or `suspend`, which I have found on lots of YouTube videos or on the MSDN site. Therefore I think I should do something with `activated` / `deactivated`, but I don't know where to add this handler. On the MSDN site I only found the function.

I am looking for something like this: [Event on returning to app, after exiting by Windows key [UWP][Win10 Mobile]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493754/event-on-returning-to-app-after-exiting-by-windows-key-uwpwin10-mobile), but as I told, I don't have `this.suspend` / `this.resume` on Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we talk about Windows Phone 8, we have to specify which app flavor is intended.

1. For Silverlight apps, there are Application_Activated() and Application_Deactivated() methods, usually they're auto-created automatically in the App.xaml.cs
2. For so called "RT apps" there are events Suspending and Resuming, 1st one is subscribed automatically in the App.xaml.cs (so just put your code into that auto-generated handler), and you have to subscribe to 2nd one by yourself.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/m6dix
i think i m using silverlight apps,right? i don t know where to see what i m using,i m relatively new.

Comment: update: 
http://imgur.com/a/m6dix
found these. how can i use them in my main code? nothing seems to work. can you please give me a short example? like when you resume program,it gives you a message box or smt. pretty thanks!

Comment: It seems you're using Silverlight apps for 8.0 (because 8.1 has that flavors split and clearly marks projects with "Silverlight" word in the Solution Explorer). So, that handlers you've found are to be called automatically by phone itself once your app is suspending or resumed back to the screen.

Comment: @Jordan, one more thing to note: once launched from Visual Studio, your app may not trigger that events (I don't remember how it's implemented in 8.0) because the app is still under Visual Studio control due attached debugger. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701292/application-life-cycle-on-a-physical-device-without-lifecycle-events/37701635#37701635